# Setting lineskip affects the caption in listings

Tags: listings, line-spacing

If I specify a `lineskip` in `lstlisting`, it affects the caption too. How can I prevent it?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
lineskip=-0.7ex,
columns=fixed,basewidth=0.5em,
captionpos=b,
caption={Long caption text that spans at least two lines to show the lineskip.}
]
one
two
three
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
%lineskip=-0.7ex,
columns=fixed,basewidth=0.5em,
captionpos=b,
caption={Long caption text that spans at least two lines to show the lineskip.}
]
one
two
three
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `caption` package with `setspace`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={stretch=1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
lineskip=-0.7ex,
columns=fixed,basewidth=0.5em,
captionpos=b,
caption={Long caption text that spans at least two lines to show the lineskip.}
]
one
two
three
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
%lineskip=-0.7ex,
columns=fixed,basewidth=0.5em,
captionpos=b,
caption={Long caption text that spans at least two lines to show the lineskip.}
]
one
two
three
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Accepted until an easy ``listings``-only solution appears.

Answer (score 0):

Patch `\lst@MakeCaption` to do `\linespread{1}`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lst@MakeCaption
  {\ignorespaces}
  {\linespread{1}\selectfont\ignorespaces}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  float,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  lineskip=-0.7ex,
  columns=fixed,
  basewidth=0.5em,
  captionpos=b,
  caption={Long caption text that spans at least two lines to show the lineskip.}
]
one
two
three
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  float,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  columns=fixed,basewidth=0.5em,
  captionpos=b,
  caption={Long caption text that spans at least two lines to show the lineskip.}
]
one
two
three
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]